# Can it be a good idea to replicate session information across microservices?

Tags: authentication, session, microservices

*Posted [to reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/microservices/comments/ff1bnv/can_it_be_a_good_idea_to_replicate_session/) after it was closed here.*

In microservice architectures, it is often recommended that each service has its own database, and that any data service A needs from service B and C should be replicated in service A's database by having B and C publish events about changed data on an internal message bus.

**Is there any compelling reason why this should not work well for sessions, too?** (I ask because I haven't seen it mentioned in any form, positive or negative.) An authentication service could publish "session created" and "session deleted" messages to be picked up by the other services that require authentication, so that the other services have links between session IDs and usernames without having to check with the auth service for each request, reducing runtime dependencies.

(I know there's OAuth and OpenID Connect and JWTs, but you'd need a message bus and statefulness to revoke them anyway, and we are creating a single first-party ecosystem of APIs to serve a single portal-like user experience where sessions seem to be simpler and make more sense. Cf. [Stop using JWT for sessions](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/).)

(I also know there's the possibility of problems with the message bus, but that's the critical backbone and something we'll have to live with anyway, and I don't think it will be a big problem in practice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bigger problem I can see immediately is that because probagation of messages in a microservice ecosystem is eventually consistent, you may end up in a situation where a request hits a service synchronously, while the session info hasn't reached the service in question through the bus. This of course is less of a problem if everything goes through the bus in the first place, but oftentimes reads don't do that.

I don't know if this is what you refer with your comment about problems with the message bus, but the above can be a pretty major issue. This isn't so much to do about messaging per-se but more about the asynchronous nature of communication.

Comment: Very good point. I *think* it won't be a problem, because the bus and the message handling would be very quick, and the events could be sent before the sign-in request completes, but of course there are no guarantees.

Comment: The only real ways to be sure is when the business process is such that it makes it impossible OR that the process/workflow is such that ordering of actions is guaranteed. Both are pretty difficult to fully guarantee, and realistically I'd expect them to some degree if not very carefully designed. If a session can leak sensitive data this is a very dangerous thing to do imho